# Chatter Bot Corpus'Trainer' missing error

Tags: python, bots, chatterbot

I'm attempting to start working with building chat bot within python. I would really want to start programming one from scratch. I'm starting with the ChatterBot module to learn how it works. I have pip installed all modules but I'm still having trouble with 'ChatterBotCorpusTrainer'Im getting a missing error. I run python 3.7 and I have the updated ChatBot module.

```html
from chatterbot import ChatBot
from chatterbot.trainers import ChatterBotCorpusTrainer
import os

bot= ChatBot('Bot')
trainer = ChatterBotCorpusTrainer(bot)


corpus_path = '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/chatterbot_corpus/data/english'


for file in os.listdir(corpus_path):
trainer.train(corpus_path + file)





conversation = [
"Hello",
"Hi there!",
"How are you doing?",
"I'm doing great.",
"That is good to hear",
"Thank you.",
"You're welcome."
]

trainer = ChatterBotCorpusTrainer(chatbot)
trainer.train('chatterbot.corpus.english')

response = chatbot.get_response("Good morning!")
print(response)
```

this is the error I'm getting

```html
/Users/singlefawn/Desktop/Our Realm/1997/Programs/random gallery/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/chatterbot/storage/jsonfile.py:26: UnsuitableForProductionWarning: The JsonFileStorageAdapter is not recommended for production environments.
  self.UnsuitableForProductionWarning
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/singlefawn/Desktop/Our Realm/1997/Programs/random gallery/chat_1_1.py", line 6, in <module>
trainer = ChatterBotCorpusTrainer(bot)
  File "/Users/singlefawn/Desktop/Our Realm/1997/Programs/random gallery/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/chatterbot/trainers.py", line 101, in __init__
from .corpus import Corpus
  File "/Users/singlefawn/Desktop/Our Realm/1997/Programs/random gallery/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/chatterbot/corpus/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
from chatterbot_corpus import Corpus
ImportError: cannot import name 'Corpus' from 'chatterbot_corpus' (/Users/singlefawn/Desktop/Our Realm/1997/Programs/random gallery/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/chatterbot_corpus/__init__.py)
```

Comment: In your own words, what do you expect `ChatterBotCorpusTrainer` to refer to, and why?

Comment: I have attempted to update the code.

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify the module (chatterbot.trainers). You have 2 options:

1

```
from chatterbot import trainers
```

2

```
trainer = chatterbot.trainers.ChatterBotCorpusTrainer
```

Comment: That helped out I updated the code, still kicking back these corpus errors>>

Comment: You haven't defined ```chatbot``` in the line: 
```trainer = ChatterBotCorpusTrainer(chatbot)```

Comment: That line also redefines ```trainer```

Comment: Im still getting this error line 12
    trainer.train(corpus_path + file)
          ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block

Comment: That line is part of your for loop so yes, it should be indented